# Is GCloud Serverless VPC connector available outside us-central1?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, vpc

Has anyone managed to create a serverless VPC connector in google cloud outside region `us-central1`?

I only seem to be able to choose `us-central1` (see image attached).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As your screenshot itself shows: “only one region is currently available”.

Comment: Thanks Mani, I just need to understand whether this is a config issue on my side or actually a GCloud constraint.I am unable to find a reference in the docs. If you have a link, please share.

Comment: @jmike - Serverless VPC Access is in a pre-release state. This often means it is not generally available. `us-central1` is the standard region for new products/services. This also means that there might be a shortage of documentation that a General Availability product/service would have. I would follow this on Google's Issue Tracker: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers